# Xcode 7 "is not on any development teams"

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I want to run my Ionic app on a iOS device.

I was following this tutorial: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/intro/deploying/

My MacOS is very old and I only can run Xcode 7. After I added my Apple ID it is not showing a personal team, it just tells me "is not on any development teams"

on other pages I read I have to readd my Account, but this didn't work for me.

What can I do?

Comment: I am trying to fix this problem for 1 day now, and I even don't know if it is possible to fix, because of my old OS

Comment: One would be limited to Xcode 7 only if their macOS is macOS 10.11.4 or older, which means that the last time you did a **security update** was in March 2016 or before.

Comment: You should nowadays give up any Xcode version that is lower than Xcode 10.1 for iOS; see https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036. And starting April 2020, you should give up any Xcode version that is lower than Xcode 11; see https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submissions/. So upgrade to a newer Mac/macOS first.